# Why pytest runner hammett not support pytest_mock?

Tags: python, pytest, mutation-testing, pytest-mock, pytest-cov

```
Pytest version = 6.0.1
Pytest-mock version = 3.6.1
Hammett version = 0.9.2

Python version = 3.9.2
```

When I try to run the test cases by using hammett getting the below error

missing 1 required positional argument: 'mocker'

After this I added some configuration in setup.cfg file as below

```
[hammett]
plugins=
 pytest_mock
```

After added above line facing below error

Assertion error: Package scopee is not support at this time.

Note: I didn't mention any scope in my fixture so by default it took 'function' as scope.

Comment: Probably because the fixture is named `mocker` and not `mocket`.

Comment: @hoefling that is typo error while putting question. Now I edited the descriptions